# Convex hull calculations with WIEN2k

Tags: density-functional-theory, condensed-matter, mathematical-modeling, alloys, wien2k

How does one do the calculation of a convex hull with the WIEN2k code for the formation energy of alloys?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our community! The convex hull of a shape is the smallest convex shape that contains it. Of what shape do you want the convex hull?

Comment: Are you having problems with Wien2k specifically, or are you asking what the definition of a convex hull is when calculating the stable alloying phases?

Comment: I will suggest to use Vasp or a related free PW code. I don't knoe if there is a routine that generates this job with Wien2k, but it will be expensive, besides there is a database for several material alloys.